# Error caused by android.view.InflateException and NavigationView error

Tags: java, android, xml

I followed a tutorial from the start to end but I still get this error. I have restarted my project once because of this error. Whenever I try to run it, the app crashes and shows this error in the logcat:

"Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView".

I'll post the class and xml file of the main activity, the strings,styles, drawer_menu xml and nav.header.xml files and the gradle files. I actually tried to see how others solved their problem but I can't seem to find the solution for mine. Thanks for taking a look and helping! Thanks everybody. If I need to provide more code feel free to ask! :-)

Main Activity Class

```
package com.example.samuel.a2;

import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private DrawerLayout drawer;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, 
toolbar,
    R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

Main Activity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Styles XML

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Strings XML

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">A2</string>
<string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
<string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
</resources>
```

Drawer_Menu XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
        android:title="Dashboard" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_incman"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_error_outline_black_24dp"
        android:title="Incident Management" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:title="Settings" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp"
        android:title="Logout" />
</group>

</menu>
```

Nav.header XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="176dp"
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:text="Just A Test"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test@gmail.com" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Gradle (Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.samuel.a2"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
}
```

Gradle: (Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when it crashes while inflating `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`, most likely the `nav_header.xml` or the `drawer_menu.xml` contain errors - or might be missing resources.

Comment: Hi, I don't think I have missed out anything but I'll rewatch the tutorial again!

Comment: @stanloona better check, if all of those `drawable` resources exist.

Comment: You mean the resources such as "@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"? If so, yes, all of them have been created. I copy pasted them from my previous project. Or should I just create new ones through vector asset? Thanks!